# Relate two entities using properties in Freebase

Tags: freebase, mql

I want to find out how Wenjin SU and Jimei University are related in Freebase. I have found out the Wenjin SU has a type `/business/board_member/`which has property`/business/board_member/leader_of`. How can I use this information in an Freebase MQL to extract the term or mid of Jimei University?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Freebase page for [Wenjin SU](https://www.freebase.com/m/0sxhm9v) you see that he has the type `/business/board_member/` and under that section it lists him as the `/business/board_member/leader_of` [Jimei University](https://www.freebase.com/m/03pw6w)

The first thing you should do is go to the [Query Editor](https://www.freebase.com/query) and create a skeleton MQL query for that relationship:

```
{
  "id": "/m/0sxhm9v",
  "name": null,
  "/business/board_member/leader_of": [{}]
}
```

When you run this query you get the following result:

```
{
  "result": {
    "name": "Wenjin SU",
    "/business/board_member/leader_of": [{
      "name": null,
      "type": [
        "/organization/leadership"
      ],
      "id": "/m/0sxhm9s"
    }],
    "id": "/m/0sxhm9v"
  }
}
```

This is not quite what you were asking for. It's saying that he is the `leader_of` an un-named topic [/m/0sxhm9s](https://www.freebase.com/m/0sxhm9s). Now, if you visit the Freebase page for that topic you'll see that its a mediator node that connects a person and their role to an organization for a specific date range. You'll also notice that Jimei University is listed as the `/organization/leadership/organization` on this page.

We can now add this mediated property to our MQL query to get the full relationship that you're looking for:

```
{
  "id": "/m/0sxhm9v",
  "name": null,
  "/business/board_member/leader_of": [{
    "/organization/leadership/organization": {
    }
  }]
}
```

If you're building an application that has a pre-determined set of relationships like this then you can use this process of exploring the Freebase data to build MQL queries for those relationships. If you're looking to find any arbitrary connection between any two entities in Freebase then you'll need to download the [Freebase Data Dumps](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data) and run a [shortest path algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path) over the entire graph.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn for the awesome answer. It would be great, though, to somehow obtain the type : `/organization/leadership/organization` from another MQL without having to go to that page and finding out that. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It is possible to find the relationship using /type/reflect/any_master as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732477/freebase-finding-relationship-between-nodes but I don't recommend that approach because its a hack that creates a lot of requests that time-out.

Comment: `/organization/leadership/organization` is a property associated with the `/organization/leadership/`.  You can get it's properties by querying the schema or by using the `"*":[{}]` idiom, but you'd still need to know which of the returned properties were important to you to know where to look in the result.